# JQuery recreates javascript object from it's method without a request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two nested javascript objects and onclick events to using them:

HTML:

```
onclick="TestObject.go(123);"
onclick="TestObject.InnerObject.innerMethod();"
```

... the second one will always fire after first. `go()` is initialization.

Javascript:

```
var TestObject = {
    justTest: -2,

    go: function(justTest) {
        // is '123' now
        this.justTest = justTest;
    },

    InnerObject: {
        innerMethod: function() {

            // alerts 123. It's ok.
            alert(TestObject.justTest);

            $(id).animate({height: '50px'}, 300, function(){

                // alerts -2 now! Why?
                alert(TestObject.justTest);
            }
        }
};
```

... why in animate function the `TestObject` being recreated?

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/sbLT5/

Comment: As a matter of design principle, code should _never_ refer to the variable to which it has been assigned (i.e. `TestObject`) from inside itself.  Its a refactoring nightmare, and those variables can change, or be reassigned to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that javascript code does not work, this does:

```
var TestObject = {
  justTest: -2,

  go: function (justTest) {
      // is '123' now
      this.justTest = justTest;
  },

  InnerObject: {
      innerMethod: function () {

          // alerts 123. It's ok.
          alert(TestObject.justTest);

          $(id).animate({ height: '50px' }, 300, function () {

              // alerts -2 now! Why?
              alert(TestObject.justTest);
          })
      }
  }
};
```

I tested it and it gives me the "123" alert both times..

Comment: Yes, the OP has syntax errors in the code they posted, but if their actual code contained this errors as well, the `alert` inside the `.animate` callback would not even be executed. But apparently it does for the OP. So all your post is saying is that their code works, in which case the question should be closed instead of answered.

Comment: but your code is equal to my. Or you just run this code yourself and its works?

Comment: @Yamaha: It's not equal to the code you posted, you are missing the `)` of the `.animate(...)` call. But Pablo seems to like the "spot the difference" game.

Comment: @Yamaha is not the same code, check the last lines and you'll se the difference, also i tested it and it works fine..

Comment: @FelixKling, ah true. My fail, sry.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez just saying `this code works` isn't much of an explanation